# Rails views to get variable from controller

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using form with :remote => true for ajax functionality, this form works fine but outside this form I have select_tag for other feature :

```
        <%= select_tag "months", options_for_select(@dynamic_month.collect { |name|
            name  }, 'ALL'), id: 'chart_filter', :onchange =>"monthWise(this)"  %>
```

Here I'm passing @dynamic_month from controller, but I'm not getting updated value from controller after submission of form, Is there any way we can achieve this keeping this select option outside the form and getting updated data from controller.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use instance method in select_tag, instance need refresh page to update, instead use form success data to update select_tag options.

Comment: Thanks, I have solved the problem using jquery.